# Convert SSIS Object variable to String/Varchar(MAX) to pass it as a parameter for another stored procedure

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have an "Execute SQL Task" in SSIS have a SQL `SELECT` query which return a `Varchar(MAX)` value, and I am assigning that to a SSIS string variable, with `resultset as single row`, which is throwing an error regarding casting.

So I changed SSIS Variable type to an Object.

Now the problem is I have another "Execute SQL Task" which uses this SSIS variable as a parameter to a stored procedure, but it is of type VARCHAR(MAX). How can I achieve it?

Basically I am trying to get a SSIS Object Variable to Varchar(MAX) or String variable to pass it into another stored procedure.

Comment: too many loopholes. Are you sure you want a `object` variable and not `string` ? If so, why don't you use `full result set` ? What exactly your `SELECT` query is returning ? Is it giving 1 row or multiple rows ?

Comment: Is the `select` and the `SP` in the same database? Just write one piece of T-SQL to do it all

Comment: I am pretty sure with single row that you can assign each column to a variable

Comment: You need to fix the error that you get when trying to store the result in a string variable.  Unfortunately you didn't tell us what the error is so we can't assist you further until you provide more information.

Comment: I am getting a single row with more than 8000 characters and I don't want the data from SQL to get truncated. So I used Object variable in SSIS (Working perfectly fine if I use string Variable in SSIS and SQL query as VARCHAR(8000),but data got truncated). SQL and the final Stored Proc are in different db. I tried to read the value from the object ans assign it to a string variable using a script Task but I could see only 'System._COMObject' as value.

Answer (score 1):

Change your variable type back to string and use:

```
CAST([YourColumn] AS varchar(8000)) AS [YourVariableResultName]
```

If it doesn't, post the error you get when you do the casting

Comment: If I CAST it my data get truncated at 8000 characters. Is that right?

Comment: @ShibinG That's right, yes. If the value is more than 8000 characters then you will need to consider solution? If the data is in the same database as your stored procedure, then you can do it all in the stored procedure. If its from another database then you might consider getting the data to the database where the SP sits (possiblly a data flow task) before the execute sql task that runs your SP

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved . Changed the execute SQL task Result set to full result set and assign it to an object variable.Then used a Foreach item container and set that object variable as source and assigned the 0 index value into a string variable . Then passed it to the stored procedure.Thank you all for your help.,☺️